# Language translate grammar

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add another language for my project.

[image: I am using database table for words. Like this screenshot.]

We know that languages can show differences in subject and predicate. 
For example:

English: **Mustafa** went to the cinema with his friend **ahmet** today.

Turkish: **Mustafa** bugün arkadaşı **ahmet** ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.

English   -  Turkish

today     =>     bugün

sinema    =>     cinema

birlikte  =>     with

gitti     =>     went

Mustafa and ahmet is username from users table. My question is how can I show the words with good grammars?

If I want to add my example word in my language table what should I do? I am asking this because of this example:

```
$username => Mustafa,

$friendname => ahmet
```

English: `<?php echo $username;?>` went to the cinema with his friend `<?php echo $friendname;?>` today.

Turkish: `<?php echo $username;?>` bugün arkadaşı `<?php echo $friendname;?>` ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.

As you can see, the special names are in different places. How can I show the usernames from the table without echoing it?

Comment: There is no trivial solution for your problem.

Comment: You can str_replace something like "{{USERNAME}} went to the cinema with his friend {{FRIENDNAME}}  today." --- "{{USERNAME}} bugün arkadaşı  {{FRIENDNAME}} ile birlikte sinemaya gitti."

Comment: $eddie i have tried this but it is not showing USERNAME and FRIENDNAME it shows the word like this. `{{USERNAME}} went to the cinema with his friend {{FRIENDNAME}} `

Comment: I mean you have to replace it. It is just a placeholder.

Comment: @eddie Can you show me within example please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont use placeholder on defined sentences.

```
$sentences = array();
$sentences[ "en" ] = "{{USERNAME}} went to the cinema with his friend {{FRIENDNAME}} today.";
$sentences[ "tu" ] = "{{USERNAME}} bugün arkadaşı {{FRIENDNAME}} ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.";
```

Put the name and placeholders on array

```
$placeHolder    = [ "{{USERNAME}}", "{{FRIENDNAME}}" ];
$name           = [ "Mustafa", "ahmet" ];
```

If you choose to print `EN`

```
echo str_replace($placeHolder, $name, $sentences[ "en" ]);
```

Will result to: *Mustafa went to the cinema with his friend ahmet today.*

If you choose to print `TU`

```
echo str_replace($placeHolder, $name, $sentences[ "tu" ]);
```

Will result to: *Mustafa bugün arkadaşı ahmet ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.*

Comment: You taught a very simple and effective way. Thank you so much.

Comment: `$placeHolder    = [ "{{USERNAME}}", "{{FRIENDNAME}}" ];` giving this problem: `Notice: Array to string conversion in`

Comment: There should no problem with that part of the code. Maybe on `str_replace` part

Comment: You have to make sure that the number of array items in `$placeHolder` and `$name` are the same.

Comment: How about try this instead

Comment: $placeHolder  = array( "{{USERNAME}}", "{{FRIENDNAME}}" );
$name    = array( "Mustafa", "ahmet" );

Comment: @Eddie There is no difference between `array()` and `[]`

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt, Yeah you are right but `[]` is only available as of PHP 5.4. I was thinking that he is maybe hes using lower version.

Comment: He would get a syntax error rather then a notice if he would use <PHP5.4 (which he shouldt no matter what).

Comment: Probable you are right. Im just covering all the possible reason. The author of this post didnt post any more issues, so it might ( or might be a different solution ) solved the problem.

Comment: @Eddie Manuel Mannhardt is right. It is not working now. Code was working before, but not working right now.

Comment: @Eddie There is a new question about your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631661/php-str-replace-wont-work-for-translating-word

Comment: @Eddie why you used str_replace ? preg_replace is working also.