# php str_replace wont work for translating word

Tags: php

I am trying to add translate word for my project. But the str_replace doesn't work.

I have a database table for language.

If user choosed *English* then for example user see this word:

English: **Mustafa** went to the cinema with his friend **ahmet** today.

If user choosed *Turkish* then for example user see this word:

Turkish: **Mustafa** bugün arkadaşı **ahmet** ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.

I have used str_replace like this:

```
    $splaceHolder = array( "{{username}}", 
                           "{{otherusername}}" ); 

    $sname = array( "<a href='".$base_url.$username."'>".$username."</a>", 
                    "<a href='".$base_url.$otherusername."'>".$otherusername."</a>" );
```

and `str_replace` here:

```
$note = str_replace($splaceHolder, $sname, $lang['text'][$lang]);
```

The `$lang['text'][$lang]` be coming from language table and text is for English:

```
{{username}} went to the cinema with his friend {{otherusername}} today.
```

For Turkish:

```
{{username}} bugün arkadaşı {{otherusername}} ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.
```

str_replace doesn't work here.

It show for english this `{{username}} went to the cinema with his friend {{otherusername}} today.` to this ***Mustafa*** went to the cinema with his friend **ahmet** today.

for show for Turkish this `{{username}} bugün arkadaşı {{otherusername}} ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.` tho this  ***Mustafa*** bugün arkadaşı **ahmet** ile birlikte sinemaya gitti.

But I only geting like the following way.

> {{username}} went to the cinema with his friend {{otherusername}}
>   today.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question just a moment ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629103/language-translate-grammer

Comment: @Andreas That is not str_replace question.

Comment: But the answer is. And you just removed the "accept" of his answer.

Comment: @Andreas That answer is not enough i just asked a new question no need to give me mines vote.

Comment: I havn't. I have not voted on any of your question or answers (as far as I can remember).

Comment: Try `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`

Comment: @Gunaseelan preg_replace is solved problem but how. Why str_replace doesn't work.

Comment: @DevStud `preg_replace` is for pattern search and replace that no need for encoding where as `str_replace` is for string search that needs encoding.

Answer (score 1):

str_replace works for your example.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $string = "{{username}} went to the cinema with his friend {{otherusername}} today.";

    $res = str_replace("{{username}}", "firstuser", $string);
    $res = str_replace("{{otherusername}}", "seconduser", $res);
    echo "result: ".$res."<br />";
?>
```

Even you can perform both replaces with a single line:

```
$res = str_replace(["{{username}}", "{{otherusername}}"], ["firstuser", "seconduser"], $string);
```

Works for me.

Comment: yes it is working fine not have any problem. But the text will be come from table then problem happening on that time.

Comment: Then you must have some problems with the encoding, maybe your database is not in utf8 which is the default encoding that php uses and you should change the encoding of the database string before using str_replace. You should first find out which encoding is using your database and then have a look at php iconv function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: gunaseelan answer : Try `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` solved my problem.  So your answer is good i have try it also.